# Mapping Google Calendar events

Tags: google-calendar, google-maps

I would like to display a Google Map with all of my calendar events such that the user can see points on the map relating to the locations of different events. When they click on the point it should show the event and also when they click on an event they should be taken to that part of the map.

I see [this](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=zHrjP-hC97ws.kFrN9blJfyg8&hl=en_US), but I'm not sure how to do it myself.

Comment: If you expand the information on the right in your sample, it says: _"Enter the RSS URL of a public Google Calendar, grab the "More options - KML" URL, and paste it into a Google maps search box to get your embeddable map."_ Unfortunately, [Google has discontinued XML feeds for calendars](https://www.404techsupport.com/2015/10/google-discontinue-feed-google-calendars/). So at the moment there doesn't appear to be an official, Google-only way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Is there ANY way to do this?

Comment: You might craft up your own CSV with the information needed.

Comment: @Al E. - I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/chadn/mapfilter) which does exactly what I need. I can run it from my server as well. Here's the [example](http://chadnorwood.com/gcm/?gc=geocachingspain@gmail.com&ed=180).